# Monty Hall problem with pre-specified probabilites

Tags: probability

Suppose that a player is given the probabilities for a prize behind each of the three doors. $p_1$, the probability of the prize being behind door 1, is $p_1=\frac{1}{2}$, the other probabilities are $p_2 = \frac{1}{3}$, $p_3 = \frac{1}{6}$.

The player chooses door 1 and after his choice one of the doors 2 or 3 is randomly revealed behind which the prize does not reside and the player is offered to change his choice.

The question is: Should the player still change his decision after one of the doors was revealed?

I'm having trouble with this problem, since I don't really know how to interpret the probabilities given at the start of the game. Since door 1 is more likely than the others to have the prize, it seems logical that after one of the doors was revealed the probability of door 1 having the prize should increase, but I cannot explain this probabilistically.

My attempt:

Let A = door 1 has the prize, B = door 2 has prize, C = door 3 has prize.

Let D = door 2 is chosen, E = door 3 is chosen.

We're looking for $P(A|D)+P(A|E)\gt P(A)$?

But I'm having trouble finding $P(A|D)$ and $P(A|E)$. Using Bayes I could write $P(A|D)=\frac{P(D|A)P(A)}{P(D)}$, but then again it seems as if the choice of door 2 or door 3, i.e. D or E are independent of A. I'm just sort of confused right now and I'm kind of under time pressure, so I' very much appreciate some help.

Comment: Picking door 1 first is a terrible strategy. I would much rather choose door 3 first and then switch.

Comment: @DavidK nice point! The problem is given as him choosing Door 1, but door 3 would give $P(Win)=5/6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always be 1/2.

Let $D_1$ be the probability that the prize is behind door 1, and $P(D_o)$ be the probability that it is behind the unrevealed door. We know that $P(D_1\cup D_o)=1$, right? These events are disjoint, so: $P(D_1\cup D_o)=P(D_1)+P(D_o)=1\implies P(D_o)=1/2$

The desirability of switching in the $N$-door monty hall problem is entirely dependent on your initial accuracy. Say you are able to select the door with $99.99999\%$ accuracy, would you switch, no. But, say you were have only $0.0000001\%$ accuracy, then you will always benefit from switching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand why the probability for door 1 will still be 1/2 after only two doors remain. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @eager2learn I just derived it in my post. You don't gain any more information about the door you selected by Monty showing you the other doors. Thus, you still have the same odds of being right. The monty hall problem really doesn't require conditional probability...you have two mutually exclusive choices, and you already know the probability of one of them.

Comment: @eager2learn basically, 50% of the time, if you decide to stick with your selected door, you would have won. The other 50% of the time, you would have won had you switched. Thus, each choice has the same odds.